# Group a json data into list based on key trailing number

Tags: c#, json

I got a json result as shown in image 1 but I need an output shown in image 2[image].
[image]

I took the following classes

```
public class NameDTO
        {
            public string Name;
        }

        public class ValDTO
        {
            public string Val;
        }
```

I got the list to the above classes as shown in figure 3 and 4 and combining them and converting to json.
[image]

[image]

```
var combined1 = _nameDetials1.Zip(_valDetials1, (name1, val1) => new { name1.Name, val1.Val })                                               .ToDictionary(k => k.Name, k => k.Val);

var jsonSerialiser1 = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json1 = jsonSerialiser1.Serialize(combined1);
```

How can I do the grouping so that I can get he correct output as shown in image2

Thanks.

Comment: None of the code snippets you show are C, so I changed the language tag to C# (which I assume you're using). Please use correct tags in future questions.

Comment: Yes.. I am using c#. I missed it by mistake. Will make sure of that.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible you can use Json.NET.
Here an example to solve your problem.

```
const string JSON = @"{
    ""message-Code-1"": ""000"",
    ""msg-Number-Pos1-1"": ""0000"",
    ""msg-Number-Pos2-1"": ""1"",
    ""msg-Number-Pos3-1"": ""1"",
    ""message-Code-2"": ""1"",
    ""msg-Number-Pos1-2"": ""0001"",
    ""msg-Number-Pos2-2"": ""2"",
    ""msg-Number-Pos3-2"": ""1"",
    ""message-Code-3"": ""0002"",
    ""msg-Number-Pos1-3"": ""3"",
    ""msg-Number-Pos2-3"": ""1"",
    ""msg-Number-Pos3-3"": ""1"",
    ""message-Code-4"": ""0003"",
    ""msg-Number-Pos1-4"": ""3"",
    ""msg-Number-Pos2-4"": ""1"",
    ""msg-Number-Pos3-4"": ""1""
}";

JObject loMessages = JObject.Parse(JSON);
JArray loMessageArray = new JArray();
JObject loAddMessage;
foreach (var loMessageGroup in loMessages.Properties().GroupBy(item => Regex.Match(item.Name,@".*-(?<pos>\d+)").Groups["pos"].Value))
{
    loAddMessage = new JObject();
    foreach (var loMessage in loMessageGroup)
        loAddMessage[loMessage.Name] = loMessage.Value.ToString();
    loMessageArray.Add(loAddMessage);
}
Console.WriteLine(loMessageArray.ToString());
```

The Json Ouput is like this:

```
[
  {
    "message-Code-1": "000",
    "msg-Number-Pos1-1": "0000",
    "msg-Number-Pos2-1": "1",
    "msg-Number-Pos3-1": "1"
  },
  {
    "message-Code-2": "1",
    "msg-Number-Pos1-2": "0001",
    "msg-Number-Pos2-2": "2",
    "msg-Number-Pos3-2": "1"
  },
  {
    "message-Code-3": "0002",
    "msg-Number-Pos1-3": "3",
    "msg-Number-Pos2-3": "1",
    "msg-Number-Pos3-3": "1"
  },
  {
    "message-Code-4": "0003",
    "msg-Number-Pos1-4": "3",
    "msg-Number-Pos2-4": "1",
    "msg-Number-Pos3-4": "1"
  }
]
```

Comment: No. This might not work, since I have to again re-frame my string i.e. const string JSON in your context.